# How to set Content-Type header in Coffeescript POST request

Tags: html, coffeescript, httprequest

I am trying to send a POST request to a `Jenkins` remote access api, and need to set the `Content-Type` header to **'application/xml'** for the request to work.
I have tried setting it with `.headers(Authentication: auth, Content-Type: 'application/xml')` to no avail. The request doesn't even go through when I pass in the Content-Type argument. If I submit the request without the `Content-Type` argument, the html that comes back includes `<h1>Error</h1>No Content-Type header`.

This is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
msg.http(url)
  .headers(Authorization: auth, Content-Type: 'application/xml')
  .query(name: name)
  .post(config_xml) (err, res, body) ->
    msg.send "POSTed"
```

Comment: what kind of object is the `msg` object, you're invoking the method on?

Comment: It's an argument passed to the robot.respond function of a hubot script, which is a chat robot written by GitHub

Comment: It's an instance of the Response object, defined here: https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/src/response.coffee

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding quotes around the Content-Type field in the call to headers.

```
.headers(Authorization: auth, 'Content-Type': 'application/xml')
```